# jquery.each looping multiple objects

Tags: jquery

I have two objects to traverse at the same time. for example:

```
var param1= [1,2,3];
var param2= ["a","b","c"];

jQuery.each ((param1,param2), function (key,value){
alert (param1,param2);
}
```

desired result: 1a 2b 3c

is there a way to achieve this using jQuery.each? or an alternate in jQuery.

Thanks

Comment: `var param1= {1,2,3};` is invalid. its not an array nor in json format

Comment: Are those really objects, not arrays?

Comment: And `alert()` only takes one parameter.

Comment: Objects don't preserve the order of elements, so you can't expect them to line up like `1a 2b 3c`, you could get `1b 2c 3a`.

Comment: my bad .. i have fixed original question

Answer (score 1):

If you change them to arrays, you can use `$.each` to traverse one of them, and then use the index to access the corresponding elements in the other array.

```js
var param1 = [1, 2, 3];
var param2 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
$.each(param1, function(index, value1) {
  var value2 = param2[index];
  console.log(value1 + value2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery.each function first parameter should be an array and second should be the callback,
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

you don't need to use jquery each function you can do this in pure javascript with a simple logic.

```
var param1= [1,2,3];
var param2= ['a','b','c'];
for(var i=0;i<(param1.length>param2.length?param1.length:param2.length);i++) { 
alert(typeof param1[i]!='undefined'?param1[i]:'');
alert(typeof param2[i]!='undefined'?param2[i]:'');}
```